Orthonormal system build upon a Fourier Transform
I'm currently taking a Fourier Transform course and I have to solve the next problem:
"Suppose you have a function $f$, continuous in $[0,1]$ and with compact support also $[0,1]$ (that is, $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin[0,1]$) and that has $||f||_2=1$ (that is $((\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^2)^{1/2}=1)$ then prove that $(\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i n\xi})_n$ is an orthonormal system in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$"
I've no problem demonstrating that f is integrable so the Fourier transform exists. Also, I have this:
$$\langle \hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i n\xi},\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i m\xi}\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i n}\bar{\hat{f}(\xi)}e^{-2\pi i m}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2e^{2\pi i (n-m)\xi}d\xi$$
This shows that if n=m, using that the Fourier transform preserves the norm in $L^2$, then
$$\langle \hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i n\xi},\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i n\xi}\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2e^{2\pi i (n-n)\xi}d\xi=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2d\xi=||\hat{f}||_2^2=||f||_2^2=1$$
However when $n\neq m$ I don't know how to show that the integral is 0, any clue on how to do it?

You can probably show that in many ways, but more interesting is to look at those basis functions of the orthonormal system and trying to understand what they are, maybe by transforming them in some, eh... appropriate way!

A hint for you is to look at the problem in the physical space rather than the Fourier space. The functions are all modulations of a given function. What is the Fourier transform of $\hat f(\xi)e^{2\pi i n\xi}$?
